# How to get size of char* x[]

Tags: c++

How would I get the size of this:

```
 char* stringit[4] = {"H","H","UH","i"};
```

I tried:

```
sizeof(stringit);
```

and it outputed 32.

I tried to make a for loop:

```
for (i= 0; check != 0; ++i){
    check = stringit[i];
}
```

and that did not work either. Is there anyway to do this without having to pass in the size of the array?

Comment: You have to pass the size of the array around with the array afaik.

Comment: What do you expect the size to be and what do you think that size represents? It's important that we know whether you understand your own question :-)

Comment: And `std::vector<std::string>` doesn't work because...?

Comment: "... having to pass in the size ...". Pass in *where*? I don't see any passing in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to get the number of elements of an array is to divide its actual size (in bytes) by the size of an element:

```
sizeof(stringit) / sizeof(stringit[0])
```

But unless you have extremely specific requirements, you should use a standard container like [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (and [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) too instead of `char*` C strings):

```
std::vector<std::string> stringit = {"H","H","UH","i"};
std::cout << stringit.size();
```

As @KonradRudolph mentioned, `vector` is nice if your number of elements is variable. If the number of elements is known at compile time and will never change you could instead use [`array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<std::string, 4> stringit = {"H","H","UH","i"};
std::cout << stringit.size();
```

Comment: A priori there’s nothing wrong with using a fixed-size array, the C-style array is just a bit inflexible and not type safe because it decays to pointers; `std::array` is a better replacement.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: right, I always seem to forget `array` but it is indeed a good choice if the size will always be the same. I'll edit.

Answer (score 7):

make it a NULL terminated array of pointers

```
 char* stringit[] = {"H","H","UH","i" , NULL };
```

Then just count the pointers until you find a null pointer.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to put 5 elements into an array with 4 elements, tho'.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have access to the array itself, i.e. as long as you have not converted it to a pointer, the number of elements can be calculated as

```
sizeof stringit / sizeof *stringit
```

which will evaluate to a compile-time constant `4` in your case.

Whether this is what you are looking for or not depends on some additional details, which you did not provide in your question. You mention "having to pass in the size of the array". Pass *where*?

Answer (score 2):

```
char* stringit[4] = {"H","H","UH","i"};
```

is an array of 4 strings, i.e. array of 4 `char*` (pointer holds an address, 64bit address = 8 bytes). That's why you get 32. To retrieve the number of elements, you could do:

```
int count = sizeof(stringit) / sizeof(stringit[0]);
```

which will give you 4. But note that this kind of approach isn't much flexible and I'd rather use some STL container, i.e. `std::vector<char*>` or yet even better, get rid of C-style strings as well and use `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: I feel it's important to mention that the sizeof will only work on static arrays, otherwise it will only return the size of the pointer type, and this also includes when a static array is passed into a function in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

32 is the right size. The variable stringit is an array of 4 char pointers, and each pointer is 8 bytes.

What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Who says it's always going to have 4 elements and since when are pointers definitely 8 bytes?

Comment: What?? I'm not asserting any of these things in general. I am just saying that's what he's got. His machine seems like a 64 bit machine, with 8 byte pointers, and he's got an array with 4 elements in it. So the sizeof value he is getting makes sense. I am just asking why he is surprised by that result, and what is that he is really after.

Comment: I just read it the wrong way then I guess. Explicitly referring to a specific environment is a good idea in order not to allow false conclusions to be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

The sizeof works for static arrays.  It's giving you the size of the construct in bytes.
If you want length, do `sizeof(stringit) / sizeof(char*)`.
For a more flexible solution that is probably the ``Right way" to do things in C++ (which works for dynamic arrays), just use std::array, or std::vector/std::list, if you need more dynamic allocation.

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

With this construct, you can simply use a `size()` member.

Remember to pass by reference when necessary to avoid needless copying.